# como puedo hacer una validacion de email en android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

```
        private void registrarUsuarios() {
            ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this, "bd_usuarios", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

            if(campoId.getText().toString().isEmpty()||campoNomCompleto.getText().toString().isEmpty()||campoCorreo.getText().toString().isEmpty()||campoContrasenia.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                    ||campoContraseniaRep.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LLene todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                
            }else {

                try {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_ID, campoId.getText().toString());
                    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE_COMPLETO, campoNomCompleto.getText().toString());
                    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CORREO, campoCorreo.getText().toString());
                    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CONTRASENIA, campoContrasenia.getText().toString());
                    values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_CONTRASENIA_REP, campoContraseniaRep.getText().toString());

                    Long idResultado = db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO, Utilidades.CAMPO_ID, values);
         //         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario Registrado Correctamente: " + idResultado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario Registrado Correctamente: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    db.close();
                    limpiar();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
}
```

todavia no entiendo tanto android studio, pero de que forma podre realizar un validadacion email? se lo agradeceria, nuestro profe no alcanzo  a pasar la materia de android studio:( paso  puro ppt jsjsj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor es usar expresiones regulares(REGEX),yo uso lo siguiente para validar correos

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9]+(\\.?[a-z0-9])*)+@(([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+))+");
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, saludo...

Answer (score 1):

Para validar un correo, la manera mas sencilla es tener en cuenta que un email pose `minimo` un `punto .` y un `arroba @`,  asique podrias hacer la comprobacion de que el campo `CAMPO_CORREO` posee esos elementos.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias.........

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer], saludos